# How to convert date string from database to something comparable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime, timestamp

I have timestamps in database formatted like this: `2022-05-03 10:20:30.687 +0200`.

I'm trying to convert that to a format that would allow me to compare two timestamps.

But, when I try to print that with

```
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(last_timestamp, pytz.utc))
```

I get the following error:

```
E       TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

How can I get this to work?

**Edit:**

It appears I was overthinking this: comparing the strings directly works as expected.

Comment: Compare strings directly will not work in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
time_stamp1=str('2022-05-03 10:20:30.687 +0200')
time_stamp2=str('2022-05-04 11:21:35.687 +0200')
t1 = datetime.strptime(time_stamp1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z")
t2 = datetime.strptime(time_stamp2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z")

diff = t1 - t2
```

check [datetime python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for more

Answer (score 0):

As you can read from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp), the `datetime.fromtimestamp` function converts a date in posix format (a 32bit integer) to a local date format.

> Return the local date and time corresponding to the POSIX timestamp,
> such as is returned by time.time(). If optional argument tz is None or
> not specified, the timestamp is converted to the platform’s local date
> and time, and the returned datetime object is naive.

If your date is in string format, use the  function `datetime.strptime(date_time_str, format)`